# Fourier transform of $f_a(x)= a^{-2}\exp(-|x|^a)$, $a \in (0,2)$, is decreasing in $a$

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

Can one show that Fourier transform of 
$$ f_a(x) = a^{-2} \exp(-|x|^a), \qquad a \in (0,2)$$
is decreasing in $a$?

I have a solution for $a \in (0,1]$ which cannot be used for $a\in (1,2)$.

Comment: @user44191: Doesn't look like a homework to me.

Comment: First of all it is not a homework. If you think it is a trivial question -please  just refer me to a textbook.  There is no closed form expression for Fourier for exp(-|x|^a) for any a in (0,2], just for a=1 and a=2. Context I am researching positive definite radial functions. I have solved the problem for a \in (0,1) and x\in R^d by using results from theory of k-times monotone functions.

Comment: @TanyaApanasovich: There must be a typo in your question: $f_a(0) = a^2$ is *increasing* in $a$, and hence the integral of the Fourier transform of $f_a$ is *increasing* in $a$. In fact, the Fourier transform of $f_a$ seems to be increasing in $a$ near the origin, but of course not in a neighbourhood of infinity (because tails become lighter as $a$ grows).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki, yes, thank you, it should be exp(-||x||^a)a^{-\delta}, x \inR^d, \delta depends on d, for d=1, it is 2

Comment: I apologize; I misread the initial problem, and have retracted my close vote. That said, I do think the command in the original question ("Show that") contributed to the misreading and made me think it was taken from an exercise. For future reference, it's often better to phrase it as a question, especially because if you don't have a proof, then the conclusion is still in doubt.

Comment: @user44191 it was badly stated, I should know better.  How I approached the problem- I took a derivative with respect to a, given that I can exchange integration and derivative, I need to show that  Fourier  transform of \exp(-|x|^a)(|x|^a log(|x|^a)+2) is positive

Comment: @AlapanDas: It is $F_a(z) = 2 a^{-2} \int_0^\infty e^{-x^a} \cos(2\pi x z) dx$, and as I understand, $z \in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary and fixed.

Comment: @AlapanDas you made a mistake when taking a derivative with respect to a,  \partial (x^a)/\partial a  - it is x^a log(x). Also Fourier of exp(-x^a) is not monotone in a

Comment: @TanyaApanasovich : Can share your solution for $a\le1$ (maybe by a link)? Also, plotting suggests your desired result holds even with $a^{-1}$ (but not with $a^{-0}$) in place of $a^{-2}$.

Comment: @AlapanDas I do not know how you conclude the integration will be positive, cos is an oscillating function (positive and negative). Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I study positive definite functions. Positive definite function has a non-negarive Fourier transform. There is a sufficient condition, called multiple monotonicity.  I can exchange integral and derivative  - so I need to show that  f(x)=\exp(-x^a)(x^a log(x) +2/a) is positive definite. Using multiple monotonicity, for d=1, x \in  R^1 ,  I just need to show that f(x) is positive, non-increasing and convex. I take two derivatives and show that.  This sufficient condition does not work for a>1.

Comment: @Tanya Apanasovich Obviously that isn't necessary. But due to $e^{-x^a}$ function I just assumed that the value of integration will be positive. That's just an assumption based on data. That's why I said I am not sure whether it will be positive or negative, when $z$ is around $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Maybe Bernstein's theorem on monotone functions will help? It implies that f_a is a nonnegative mixture of gaussians.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal Not really, at least I cannot see how I can  focus on $a.$ The nice closed form expression for general $a$ does not exist

Comment: @AlapanDas why z around 1/4

Comment: @SandeepSilwal: Have you tried that? I remember that I checked that the derivative of $f_a$ is not of the form $\exp(-\phi(x^2))$ for a complete Bernstein function $\phi$. However, I do not remember now if I tried to check whether it is of the form $\psi(x^2)$ for a completely monotone $\psi$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I just checked, its not of that form I think.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki the derivative is not complete monotone, for sure. For $a\le 1$ the derivative is k-times monotone for various choices of  power $\delta$.  When $a>1$ the derivative cannot be k - times monotone for any delta.

Comment: try the explicit formula in terms of Bessel functions of the first kind together with the power series expansion for it. See the article by Blumenthal and Getoor https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-095-02/S0002-9947-1960-0119247-6/

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, thank you, I have tried it, but since the Bessel function of first kind can be positive and negative- did not help a bit, unless I am missing something. Taking a derivative with respect to $\alpha$ brings me to a more complicated problem to show that a function $\exp(-x^\alpha)\{x^\alpha\log(x)+2\}$ is positive definite

Comment: yes but did you try the series expansion of the Bessel function plus commuting sum and integral and computing the integrals?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam, I am not sure what you are referring to, I have tried  using  the  Maclaurin series   as in http://www.cl.eps.manchester.ac.uk/medialand/maths/pdfs/research/statistics-reports/psrr18-2009.pdf, I am interested in \alpha \in (1,2)

Comment: yes I meant the Taylor series. dead end then.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam. I am not sure whether it is a dead end in general, for me it is as the series looks like $\sum_{j=0}a_j(\alpha) (-t^2)^j$, $a_j(\alpha)>0$, but the term $(-1)^j$ is uncomfortable given that $t^{2j}$ increases with $j$ when $|t|>1$ and decreases when $|t|<1$, but series is not my expertise, may be I am missing something

Comment: very long shot but how about taking derivative in alpha term by term and perhaps in some cases show the result is positive by alternating series test lower bound? this is not expertise but just superficial brainstroming

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam it is a power series and when $t>1$, $a_j$s increase, so alternative series test is not applicable

Comment: @TanyaVladi, there is a "subordination formula"  $e^{-x^{a}} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2} \tau} p_{a}(\tau) d\tau$ (true for any $a \in (0,2)$) holds for some probability density function $p_{a}(\tau) d\tau$. If you use it then  the Fourier transform becomes $ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s^{2}/4} a^{-2}p_{a}(s^{2})ds$. Have you tried to follow this path? Looks like algebra will be different, at least now $p_{a}(s^{2})$ is nonnegative.

Comment: @PaataIvanishvili, yes it is the first thing I have tried. $p_\alpha(\tau)$ does not have a nice analytic expression. All presented expressions include some sort of integral and the dependency on $\alpha$ is very convoluted.  Let $U_p=({\sin(\pi x\alpha/2)\over \cos(\pi x/2)})^{\alpha/(1-\alpha)}{\cos(\pi x(\alpha-1)/2)\over \cos(\pi x/2)}$, the expression for $p_\alpha(t)$ is   $C_\alpha |t|^{1/(\alpha-1)} \int_{0}^1U_\alpha(x)\exp\{-|t|^{\alpha/(\alpha-1)}U_\alpha(x)\}dx $, where $C_\alpha$ is a function of $\alpha$ only, also non-trivial as it inclues power and Gamma

Comment: @TanyaVladi I believe I can prove it when the test point is sufficiently far from the origin (distances around 20 and up should be fine). Would you be interested in such partial result or you need "all or nothing"?

Comment: Not sure why none of the comments mention that exp(-|x|^a) is the characteristic function of a symmetric stable law whose corresponding density is given by the so-called Bergstom-Feller expansions.

Comment: @AndreyF  I did not mention because I do not know how that helps

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.
We have
$
\widehat{f_a}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R}  a^{-2} e^{-\vert x\vert ^a-ix \xi} dx=
2\int_0^{+\infty}  a^{-2} e^{-x^a} \cos(x\vert\xi\vert)dx, 
$
so that
$$
J_a(\xi)=-\frac{a^3}2\partial_a\widehat{f_a}(\xi)=
\int_0^{+\infty} \bigl( 2  + x^a \ln (x^a)\bigr)e^{-x^a}\cos(x\vert\xi\vert)dx,\quad\text{and}
$$
$$
aJ_a(\xi)=\int_0^{+\infty} t^{\frac 1a-1}\bigl( 2  + t \ln t\bigr)e^{-t}\cos(t^{1/a}\vert\xi\vert)dt.
$$
We note that
$
\frac d{dt}(t\ln t)=\ln t+1
$
which is positive iff $t>1/e$ so that
$
2+t\ln t\ge 2-\frac{1}{e}>0,
$
proving that $J_a(0)>0$.

Remark. Positive values of $\xi$ remain to be checked. Note that for $\chi_0$ smooth equal to 1 near 0 and vanishing outside of $[0,1]$, we have
$$
t^{\frac 1a-1}\bigl( 2  + t \ln t\bigr)e^{-t}=t^{\frac 1a-1}\bigl( 2  + t \ln t\bigr)e^{-t}\chi_0(t) +\psi(t),
$$
where $\psi$ belongs to the Schwartz space, thus as well as its cosine transform. Somehow the main part of the integral is located near $t=0$ and
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}  \cos(2π s\vert\xi\vert)  ds 2πa=π a\delta_0(\xi),
$$
which is indeed positive for $a>0$.

Comment: I am struggling to understand why Fourier transform  of  $\psi$ is positive. Can you please give me a reference to that decomposition for $\chi$ and $\psi$ you have used in the proof. Thank you

Comment: "ln+1 which is positive iff >1/ " . and it seems the only condition for positivity of that Fourier transform of the derivative .  So following your  arguments  I can replace the power in $1/\alpha^{2}$ from 2 to a smaller number as soon as it is bigger than $\exp(-1)$.   However a simple numerical analysis shows that if the power is $0.4$ and $\alpha=1.2$, the Fourier transform can be negative for some  $\omega$

Comment: @Tanya Vladi I did not write that the Fourier transform of $\psi$ is positive. I said that the $\partial_a\hat{f_a}(\xi=0)<0$. On the other hand it is indeed tempting to consider the positive function $\mathbb R_+\ni t\mapsto t^{1/a-1}(2+t\ln t)e^{-t}$ which is in $L^1$ and somewhat concentrated (in fact singular) at 0. I guess that for $\phi$  positive decreasing (and smooth), it is possible to decide the sign  of the cosine transform, if $\phi(0)$ is large enough, but this case is indeed a bit different.

Comment: About $\chi_0$ and $\psi$, I simply claim that, given a positive $T$, I can find two smooth functions on $[0,+\infty)$ such that $\chi_0(t)=1$ on $[0,T]$ and $\chi_0(t)=0$ on $[2T,+\infty)$ so that  with $\psi=1-\chi_0$, you get that $\psi$ vanishes near 0.

Comment: I guess I do not understand your proof at all. However a simple example, Fourier transform  of  $-{\partial\over \partial \alpha }[\exp(-x^{\alpha})\alpha^{-0.4}]$, for $\alpha$   can be negative for some $\omega$ (just from plotting using MATLAB), but according to your arguments it should be nonnegative

Comment: The only thing that I claimed is that $\partial_a\hat{f_a}(\xi=0)<0$ which does not preclude what happens for $\xi >0$.

Comment: but it is obvious as Fourier of $-{\partial\over \partial a} [\exp(-x^a)a^{-2}]$ is a positive definite function

Comment: I can calculate all the derivatives at $0$ of Fourier transform of the derivative with respect to $\alpha$,as I can express it as an analytic function $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} { (-t^2)^m a_m \over m! }$  how does it help me?

Comment: Following this : https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0004972700047511 , esp., the section "Complex Detours". I examined numerically the second derivative of $J_{\alpha}$ with a slightly complex $x$ (imaginary part ca 0.1 i ). The real part of the second derivatve seemed to fullfil the  requirements indicated in the paper for $J_{\alpha}$ to be positive for $x>0$, at least for $1 < \alpha \le 1.5$. Maybe one could look in that direction, although the proof might be tedious.

Comment: @JohannesTrost, how do you choose $p$? I have tried  to see if it works numerically,  It seems $p$ should be small. However I failed to find $p$ for $\alpha>1.5$. Like you said $\alpha<1.5$ seems to be working

Comment: @JohannesTrost, the imaginary part is not decreasing for $\alpha>1$. the problem is around $0$

Comment: @Tanya Vladi For $a > 1.5$ (sorry for changing the name of the exponent to $\alpha$) there seems to be no imaginary shift, $p$, where the real part of th second derivative fulfils the requirement. I have seen the same.

Comment: @Tanya Vladi  The imaginary part is only increasing for very small values around 0. If you look at the asymptotic expansion of the integral for very large $|x|$ (using the methods of Bleisteins book "Asymptotic Expansion of Integrals"), one can find a lower bound to $x$ above which the claim concerning $a$ is true. The wavelength of the sine under the integral is then so large that it will not "probe" the very small $t$ values around the origin, where the imaginary part increases. This is more a physicists handwaving argument, though. To prove this rigorously is quite tedious, I am afraid.

Comment: @JohannesTrost, thank you. The fact that my imaginary part increasing even at small value around 0 bothers me. I need the result for all values of cosine transform argument, I have looked into asymptotics and can prove the tail of transform  is positive, which would correspond to small value of original function.   , I guess I just cannot put all the pieces together. Not my area of expertise even though the intuition is there.