# Lower bounds on analytic functions connected to Fox H

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, special-functions, analytic-functions

The question is related to the one I asked before and never got an answer to. [Fourier transform of $f_a(x)= a^{-2}\exp(-|x|^a)$, $a \in (0,2)$, is decreasing in $a$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360993/fourier-transform-of-f-ax-a-2-exp-xa-a-in-0-2-is-decreasing) . I need to demonstrate that the following function is nonnegative for $\alpha\in(1,2)$ and $\delta >1$.
$$
 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} { (-t^2/4)^{m}\over (m) !}
{
\Gamma^{\prime} \left( { \alpha +1\over \alpha}+ m { 1\over \alpha} \right) 
+\delta \Gamma \left( { 1\over \alpha} +m { 2\over \alpha}\right) \over \Gamma \left( { 1\over 2} +m\right)  },
$$
where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is a Gamma functions. One can recognize Fox-Wright function in the second term.

Here ia the background. I would like to show that the Fourier transform of
${1 \over \alpha^{\delta} } \exp(-|x|^\alpha)$ is nonincreasing in $\alpha$. Taking derivative,
$$
{\partial \over \partial \alpha } \left\{ {1 \over \alpha^{\delta} } 
 \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x^\alpha)\cos(xt) dx \right\}=
$$
$$-{1 \over \alpha^{\delta} }\int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x^\alpha)\{x^\alpha \log(x) + \delta/\alpha\}\cos(xt) dx.
$$
Using Taylor series expansion for $\cos(\cdot)$ leads to
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x^\alpha)\{x^\alpha \log(x) + \delta/\alpha\}\cos(xt) dx =
$$
$$
  {1\over \alpha^2} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} { (-t^2)^{m}\over (2m) !}
\Gamma \left( { 2m+1\over \alpha}\right) 
\left\{\gamma\left( { 2m+1\over \alpha}\right) 
\left( { 2m+1\over \alpha}\right)  +
   1+\delta \right\}=
$$
$${1\over \alpha^2} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} { (-t^2)^{m}\over (2m) !}
\left[\Gamma^{\prime} \left( { 2m+1\over \alpha}+1\right) 
+\delta \Gamma \left( { 2m+1\over \alpha}\right) \right],
$$
where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ and $\gamma(\cdot)$ are gamma and digamma functions respectively.

There is nothing special about $\delta$ I found it numerically. The connection to Fox Wright function is
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x^\alpha)\cos(xt) dx =
{1\over \alpha} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}
\Gamma\{(1+2m)/\alpha\}
{ (-t^2)^{m}\over (2m) !}=$$
$$
{\sqrt{\pi}\over \alpha} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}
{ \Gamma\{(1+2m)/\alpha\}\over \Gamma(1/2+m)}
{ (-t^2/4)^{m}\over m !},
$$