# Inequality for Fourier transform of a power exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, special-functions, fourier-transform

Let
$$
f_{\alpha}(x)=\phi_1(\alpha) \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{|x|^\alpha}{\phi_2(\alpha) }}, 
 x \in \mathbb{R}, 0<\alpha<2,
$$
where

- $\phi_1(\alpha)=\frac{\alpha}{2} 
  \left\{{\{\Gamma(3/\alpha)\}^{1/2}\over\{ \Gamma(1/\alpha)\}^{3/2}}\right\}$ and
- $\phi_2(\alpha)= \left\{{\Gamma(1/\alpha)\over \Gamma(3/\alpha)}\right\}^{\alpha/2}$.

If $\it{F}_\alpha(\cdot)$ is a Fourier transform of $f_{\alpha}(x)$,
show that
$\it{F}_{\alpha_1}(\omega) \ge \it{F}_{\alpha_2}(\omega) $,
for any $0<\alpha_1\le \alpha_2\le 2$ and $\omega\in \mathbb{R}$.

**UPDATE**. An equivalent problem is to show that Fourier transform of
$$
(\exp(-|x|^\alpha \phi_3(\alpha)))(\phi_1’(\alpha) - |x|^{\alpha}\ln|x|\phi_1(\alpha)\phi_3(\alpha) - |x|^{\alpha}\phi_1(\alpha)\phi’_3(\alpha)),
$$
$$\phi_3(\alpha)= \left\{{\Gamma(3/\alpha)\over \Gamma(1/\alpha)}\right\}^{\alpha/2},
$$
is nonpositive.
**UPDATE TO UPDATE**. Not quite an equivalent but may be somewhat easier problem.  Let
$$
f(x,\alpha)=\exp(-|x|B(\alpha))(|x|\ln |x|-A(\alpha)|x|+C(\alpha))
$$
where

- $A(\alpha) =   - \frac{\alpha}{2} \ln \left(\frac{\Gamma(3/\alpha)}{\Gamma(1/\alpha)}\right) + \frac{3}{2} \psi_0\left(\frac{3}{\alpha}\right)- \frac{1}{2} \psi_0\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$
- $B(\alpha)=\left\{{\Gamma(3/\alpha)\over \Gamma(1/\alpha)}\right\}^{\alpha/2}$
- $C(\alpha)= -\frac{1}{\phi_3(\alpha)} 
  \left[1 - \frac{3}{2\alpha}\psi_0\left(\frac{3}{\alpha}\right) +\frac{3}{2\alpha}\psi_0\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\right]$ where $\psi_0(\cdot)$ is a digamma function.

Prove that Fourier transform of  $f(x,\alpha)$ is positive for $0<\alpha<1$ or of $f(|x|^2,\alpha)$ for $0<\alpha<2$

Comment: does taking derivative $d(F_{\alpha}(\omega))/da$  lead to anything? Also I think in phi2 you meant to write $\alpha$ not p.

Comment: @ThomasKojar not really, the function  gets very complicated. The original Fourier transform does not result in a closed form and so its derivative

Comment: I was more about thinking swapping derivative and integral.

Comment: Do you have any more background context on the the little $f_{\alpha}$ eg. literature/articles ? For example, do they satisfy any pde relation in $\alpha,x$?

Comment: @ThomasKojar yes I understood,  the Fourier Transform of the derivative does not exist in a closed form . I did try to prove that the derivative has a nonnegative Fourier transform and failed ..Numerically yes the derivative has a positive Fourier transform.

Comment: Also, what about the approach from your previous question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360993/fourier-transform-of-f-ax-a-2-exp-xa-a-in-0-2-is-decreasing, is it possible to write a Bessel-like integral now with Gammas?

Comment: Can you include the integral-formula for the derivative in your post since you have it already?

Comment: @ThomasKojar the original problem is from the  field of probability it has connections to the characteristic function of the generalized gaussian distribution , I do not know much about PDE

Comment: @ThomasKojar noone solved my previous question. I will include the derivative, sure

Comment: I see. In that case, did you try showing that the derivative $f(x,\alpha)$ is positive-definite (so we can apply Bochner's as you mentioned in the previous question). For example, do we have $|f(x,\alpha)|\leq f(0,\alpha)$? In possibly showing this, it could be helpful using some of the inequalities for Gamma, such as the one for ratios  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Inequalities

Comment: I also found a nice paper online that you most likely already seen "Analytical properties of generalized Gaussian distributions". I see there they obtain formulas for the CHF in terms of the laplace transform of a different variable.

Comment: yes, I have seen it, unfortunately I did not find it helpful in my problem. I can use this Laplace to show that $F_\alpha(\omega)\ge F_2(\omega)$  though

Comment: @ThomasKojar, the maximum  is at x\to 0, but the derivative itself is not a positive function, it does not have to be, but the fact that it is not positive makes it hard to prove positive definiteness

Comment: I was talking about the derivative $f(\alpha,x)$ that you computed above not the original function $f_{\alpha}(x)$ (it is better to use a different notation eg. $g(\alpha,x)$ to avoid confusion). To show that it is positive definite possibly by showing $|g(x,\alpha)|<g(0,\alpha)$ (this is sufficient for pos.def but not necessary).

Comment: @ThomasKojar  yes, my answer concerns the derivative, the sufficient condition works, the original function is positive 
 and positive definite and it is easy to prove that as $\exp(-|x|^{\alpha/2})$ is completely monotonic

Comment: Sure. I am just asking if you tried to show that $f(\alpha,x)$ is positive definitive. For example is the following inequality false $|f(x,\alpha)|<f(0,\alpha)$ for some x or alpha? Having this for all x,alpha would give pos.def..

Comment: @ThomasKojar yes I understood and yes I can show but the argument is lengthy

Comment: @ThomasKojar the conditional you mentioned is necessary but not sufficient

Comment: yes that's what I meant sorry. It would be interesting to see if the derivative fails to satisfy it.

Comment: @ThomasKojar, yes the necessary condition works for the derivative, but  it does not help to prove the positive definiteness, more like a sanity check:)

Comment: @TanyaVladi --- there are misprints in your definitions, could you please double check --- in particular in the equation for $\phi_2$, the symbol $p$ on the right-hand-side should probably be $\alpha$, also in the exponent?; and is it correct that $\phi_3(\alpha)=1/\phi_2(\alpha)$ ?; and is $B(\alpha)$ identical to $\phi_3(\alpha)$?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker,  yes sorry \phi_2 is a function of \alpha, I have replaced p with \alpha. As for B yes it is \phi_3=1/\phi_2

Comment: apologies for insisting, but the function $f(x,\alpha)$ does not have a _real_ Fourier transform, so what do you mean when you ask for a "positive" Fourier transform? perhaps all occurences of $x$ should be replaced by $|x|$ ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, yes f(x,\alpha) is consistent with all above, should be a function of |x|

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I can even simplify it further by calling $|y|=|x|B(\alpha)$ so I will have something like $exp(-|y|)(|y|ln(|y|) -D(\alpha)|y|+E(\alpha))$

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer the "**update to update**" question:
*Is the Fourier transform of  $f(x,\alpha)=\exp(-|x|B(\alpha))(|x|\ln |x|-A(\alpha)|x|+C(\alpha))$ positive for $0<\alpha<2$?*
The answer is *no*.

I compute the Fourier transform
$F(t,\alpha)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ixt}f(x,\alpha)\,dx$
of $f(x,\alpha)$ at $t=0$,
$$F(0,\alpha)=2\int_{0}^\infty e^{-B(\alpha)x} \bigl(x \ln x-A(\alpha) x+C(\alpha)\bigr)\,dx$$
$$\qquad=-2B(\alpha)^{-2} (A(\alpha)-B(\alpha) C(\alpha)+\ln B(\alpha)+\gamma_{\rm Euler} -1).$$
This is positive for $0<\alpha<1$ and negative for $1<\alpha<2$, see the plot.
[image]

<sub>For the record, if one wishes to check my algebra, I find   
  
$A(2)=3-\gamma_{\rm Euler} -\ln 2$, $B(2)=1/2$, $C(2)=1$, $F(0,2)=16 \ln 2-12$.</sub>

Comment: @TanyaVladi --- I am confused; you changed the question, didn't you? until an hour ago your question was "Prove that Fourier transform of  $f(x,\alpha)$ is positive for $0<\alpha<2$" --- did I make a mistake there?

Comment: I made a mistake in my UPDATE UPDATE, stating something that is not equivalent.  After you posted your answer hinting that my question is wrong people lost interest in it.  Yes, I agree my UPDATE UPDATE is not  equivalent to the original question. I based it on the fact that if $f(|x|)$ is positive definite so is $f(|x|^{\alpha})$, $0<\alpha<1$ but I am not sure about it either